# Facebook API - Search inside personal posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

is there a way to search inside personal posts through facebook api?
I'm not able to find the right service.

Best,
Luca

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reference to all the available root nodes offered by the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0

From just looking at the documentation, it seems like either the [/thread](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/thread/) or [/conversation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/conversation) nodes might be what you're looking for.

You can use the [Graph Explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/) to experiment with these nodes.

Comment: Both /thread or /conversation nodes are not searchable. I already looked at the documentation and it seems it is possible only to search for overall public posts but not for personal posts.